# subset dataframe based on certain threshold in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a correlation dataframe with 381717 rows and 450 columns and no NA values, and I want to subset this dataframe for all correlations with abs value > 0.6. I have tried multiple things to use lapply and sapply on all rows and columns to subset my dataframe but I end up getting NAs, but I do see that there are a few values which should satisfy this condition.If I could get any leads on how to do this, I would be really grateful.

I know this seems like an easy issue but I am somehow unable to get the right subsetting done and would like your help!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

[image: input data]

Expected output :

[image]

Comment: Do you mean correlations between columns? Between rows? Do you want to remove columns that have no correlations with any other column?

Comment: You could use dput to extract some of your data and put the result in your question, so that people should see what shape it has ..

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = seq(1:7)
x2 = c(2,4,8,5,1,2,3)
y1 = c(9,6,5,4,8,6,4)
y2 = c(1,7,4,5,1,2,2)
df = data.frame(x1,x2,y1,y2)
corr_df = data.frame(cor(df))
corr_df$var = row.names(corr_df)
corr_df1 = reshape2::melt(corr_df, value_name = "Corr")
corr_df1[corr_df1$value > 0.6,]
```

I have created a dummy dataset and done the subset of correlation dataframe. It might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a dataframe of correlation values:

```
corr.vals<-data.frame(x1=runif(5,0,1),
                   x2=runif(5,0,1),
                   x3=runif(5,0,1),
                   x4=runif(5,0,1),
                   x5=runif(5,0,1))

row.names(corr.vals)<-c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5")
```

You should be able to select the values > 0.6, while keeping row and column names, using complete.cases() in a subsetting:

```
values_06<-corr.vals[complete.cases(corr.vals)>0.6]
```